# Code Doesn't Execute onComplete Cannot Read Data

Tags: android, firebase, reference, google-cloud-firestore, listener

I am trying to read the arrays currAmt, currDates, oldAmt, oldDates from firestore but my debugger hits recentRef.get() and nothing in the onComplete! I have been able to successfully write to firebase but I can't read. What is wrong with my onComplete or anything else? My firebase rules are set up as read, write if true and i have read external storage in android manifest (if that is even needed). Would greatly appreciate the help! Been stuck on this for the whole day.

public static void updateLog(String uid, Integer amount) {

```
    Time today = new Time(Time.getCurrentTimezone());
    today.setToNow();

    DocumentReference recentRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("log").document(uid);
    recentRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                currAmts = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("currAmt");
                currDates = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("currDates");
                oldAmts = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("oldAmt");
                oldDates = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("oldDates");
            }
        }
    });

    currAmts.add(amount);
    currAmts.remove(0);
    currDates.add(today.monthDay);
    currDates.remove(0);
    oldDates.add(currDates.get(0));
    oldAmts.add(currAmts.get(0));

    DocumentReference logRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("log").document(uid);

    logRef.update("currAmt", currAmts);
    logRef.update("currDates", currDates);
    logRef.update("oldAmt", oldAmts);
    logRef.update("oldDates", oldDates)
        .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener < Void > () {
        @Override
        public void onSuccess(Void aVoid) {
            Log.d(TAG, "Updated successfully");
        }
    });
}
```

THIS FIXES ASYNCHRONOUS PROBLEM...

public static void updateLog(final String uid, final Integer amount) {

```
    DocumentReference recentRef = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("log").document(uid);
    recentRef.get().addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<DocumentSnapshot>() {
        @Override
        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<DocumentSnapshot> task) {
            if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                DocumentSnapshot document = task.getResult();
                currAmts = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("currAmt");
                currDates = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("currDates");
                oldAmts = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("oldAmt");
                oldDates = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("oldDates");
            }
            ***updateLog2(uid, amount);
        }
    });
}
```

updateLog2 contains the other code that would get executed BEFORE properly read data from firestore in if statement

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on the task itself, what are the object's contents? Also, the way your code is written currently, it doesn't handle asynchronous content all that well. The content in your `onComplete()` handler could very well run at the very end.

Comment: It doesn't hit onComplete or the if statement. How do I handle asynchronous content with this case?

Comment: Wait sweet figured out I just put bottom part in separate function and called it under oldDates = (ArrayList<Integer>) document.get("oldDates") because like you said needs to handle asynchronous content.

Comment: is your problem resolved?

Comment: Can you post your firestore database structure?

Comment: Please add your database structure as a screenshot. Please also responde with @AlexMamo